# ¿Como poner un option de un Select como seleccionado a través de php?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Lo que quiero es que al momento de actualizar en mi CRUD, aparezca una ventana con los elementos para actualizar, pero quiero que todos mis elementos se rellenen con la información que tengo en mi base de datos para que el usuario vea lo que anteriormente registro y pueda modificar la ventana.

Mi problema es que no se cómo hacer que mi `select` pueda ponerse como seleccionado, dependiendo del dato que ingresó el usuario anteriormente al momento de su registro.

**Código de mi select**

```html
<select name="dia" class="selector" id="dia">
    <option>1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Aquí esta una imagen de lo que quiero que aparezca funcionan dos select, pero el de los días no funciona siempre me aparece el numero 1 y lo que quiero hacer es que me aparezca el valor registrado en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que aparezca seleccionado, deberías poner el atributo `selected`. Por ejemplo: `<option value="04" selected="selected">`... Sería bueno que incluyas el código PHP con lo que estás intentando así podemos ver dónde estás teniendo problemas

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos con alguna imagen? La verdad no te entiendo mucho.

Answer (score 4):

Necesitarías una función que consulte en la base de datos esa información que quieres mostrar por defecto y una vez tuvieses la información almacenada en una variable sería tan sencillo como hacer que dicha función devuelva algo como:

```
$resultado = "<option value='".$informacion."' selected='selected'>‌";
return $resultado;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya que desconocemos el código original de PHP, esta solución no puede ser de copiar y pegar, pero sería algo así:

```
/* suponemos que ya se hizo una consulta sobre el valor
previamente seleccionado por el usuario y tenemos el valor en $eleccionPrevia */

?><select><?php
for($valor = 0; $valor < 10; $valor++) {
    echo "<option value='$valor'";
    if ($eleccionPrevia === $valor) { echo ' selected="selected";}
    echo ">$valor</option>";
<?php}
?></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ejecutar una consulta contra la base de datos o directamente un contador y colocar el "selected" cuando se cumpla la condición. Te dejo un ejemplo con una query

```
<?php
$query = 'select distinct dia from tabla order by dia   '; 
$rs = pg_query($query);

$combo = 'ID: <select class="selector" name="dia" name="dia" >\n';

while ($datos = pg_fetch_array($rs)){

    $selected = '';
    if ($idDispositivo == $datos['dia']){
        $selected = 'selected';
    }

    $combo .= '<option value="'.$datos['dia'].'"" '.$selected.'>'.$datos['dia'].'</option>\n';
}
$combo .= "</select>";
?>
```

Después la variable $combo la puedes poner donde quieras con

```
<?php echo $combo ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#proyectos select,input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
                var value = $(this).attr("value");
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#proyectos #"+id+" option").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).val() == value) {
                        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
                    }
                });introducir el código aquí
                if ($(this).attr("val") == "on") {
                    $(this).attr("checked","checked");




                }
            });
```

si le pasas por atributo y luego dejas que Jquery haga el trabajo

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tipo_empresa ";
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
                        while($filas = $result1 -> fetch_array())
                        {
                                $value = $filas["value"];
                                $tipoempresa = $filas["tipoempresa"];
                                $giro2="";
                                if ($value==$giro){
                                    $giro2='selected="selected"';
                                    }
                            ?>
               <option value="<? echo $value?>" <? echo $giro2 ?>>
              <? echo $tipoempresa ?> 
              </option>
              <? } ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Hola @miguel, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)