# ¿Porque se duplican los option(creado a traves de ajax) de un select cada vez que hago click en el <select>?

Tags: html, ajax, select, options

Tengo un error que no logro detectar y necesito ayuda plis!
Tengo un <select que sus option se va duplicando las veces que lo presiono... Lei que lo podia hacer con el change() pero no funciona... sin embargo logre formular un function con ajax que trae los datos desde la BD para colocarlos en los option.
Les dejo en lo que estoy trabajando

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tipo_contacto";

$rs_con = $conexion->query($sql) or die ($conexion->error);

$json = array();

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_con)) != NULL) {
    $json[] = array(
        "id"=>$row['tipo_contacto_id'],
        "descripcion"=>$row['tipo_contacto_descripcion']
    );
}

$jsonstring=json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

?>
este es la funcion js

```
function selecttipocontacto() {
    
    console.log('Funciona seleccion del select#tipo contacto');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/autoparts_system/modulos/contactos/tipocontacto.php",
            success: function(response){
                let lista = JSON.parse(response);
                // $("#tipocontacto option").remove();
                for(let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
                    $("#tipocontacto").append(`<option value="${lista[i].id}">${lista[i].descripcion}</option>`)
                    
                }  
                
            }
    });
    

};
```

este es html

```
<p>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Elegir un tipo de contacto:</label>
                                         <select id="tipocontacto" onclick="selecttipocontacto()"> 
                                            <option value="0" >Seleccionar</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </p>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien, pero tienes el onclick en el select con la funcion `selecttipocontacto()` lo cual llama a `$("#tipocontacto").append` por eso cada vez que haces click se añade lo mismo

Comment: justo iba comentar eso, claro por eso se estan duplicando las lineas, entonces de que manera podria hacerlo? porque lo hice de esta forma y no funciona $("#tipocontacto").on('change',function(){
        console.log('Funciona seleccion del select#tipo contacto');
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "/autoparts_system/modulos/contactos/tipocontacto.php",success: function(response){
 let lista = JSON.parse(response);
                    for(let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
                        $("#tipocontacto").append(`<option value="${lista[i].id}">${lista[i].descripcion}</option>

Comment: En el JS podrias eliminar todos los `<option>` y crearlos nuevamente con tu funcion, asi: `$("#tipocontacto option").remove()`, esto declaralo como primeria linea de la funcion `selecttipocontacto()`

Comment: Aunque supongo que estas usando una funcion para que los datos se vallan actualizando no? Si no es asi, podrias implementarlo defrente con php los `<option>`

Comment: de que forma podria hacer eso @Juan? lo de php directo a los <option>

Comment: primero deberías borrar todas las opciones que tengas en el select con `$('#tipocontacto').empty()` luego hacer el `for(let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){` que tienes.

Comment: Puedes leer este post para que veas como hacerlo: [Option a un select usando PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20655/como-poner-un-option-de-un-select-como-seleccionado-a-trav%C3%A9s-de-php)

Comment: Perfecto! voy a eso... gracias